Movie about a karate girl?
This was a movie about a rebellious, American, teenaged girl who learns karate from a Japanese teacher. He has a connection with, or at least visits, her grandmother. I saw it around the year 2000, and it seemed to be set in the 1980s or 1990s.
I tried the obvious, karate girl but that doesn't seem to be the one. I also tried karate kid but that doesn't work either. I have a recollection of the title as being something like "rebel with a cause", (not to be confused with the Jimmy Dean/Natalie Wood movie from the 1950s), but that produces an obvious mismatch.
What movie was this?

The Next Karate Kid?

@SystemDown: Perhaps.

Yes, it all points to Karate Kid IV, except for the title.

@Walt: Oh, so they made sequels, so this was in the "series," even though she wasn't the first karate kid?

@TomAu - Yeah. Karate Kid IV AKA The Next Karate Kid featured a whole new main character played by a young Hillary Swank.

@SystemDown i thought the same only by reading title and body also supports the same. Look like you should answer it

Basically is it this film?

The more I look at it the more I've convinced the movie you're looking for is The Next Karate Kid (1994) AKA Karate Kid IV. It features a young Hillary Swank (of Million Dollar Baby fame) as a new Karate Kid under the tutelage of the famous Mr. Miyagi, who meets her through her grandmother. Below is the trailer.



